# How to set up a website update (Development -> Staging -> Production) on WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git, workflow

Therefore, I would like to understand what to read in order to configure the update system - Development -> Staging -> Production, (possibly Development -> Staging -> GIT -> Production.)

[image]

If in detail, files will be uploaded to Dev via PHP Storm, then I would like to transfer files from Development -> Staging (having tried a bunch of plugins, like BackupBuddy, nothing works, permanent errors), although there are useful functions, like tracking changes to website.
Enough to implement such a bunch, by analogy, it will be possible to make Staging -> Production.
But if you try to implement Staging -> GIT -> Production, then again there are questions, as I usually add files to GIT by hand. Is there any information on how to implement the automatic addition of files on GIT, so that you can then roll back in case anything happens?

Don't hit hard, I’m digging search engines for 4 weeks, but in fact I could only find plugins that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check All-in-one WP Migration with this plugin you can create a local, staging and production setup and this plugin can update your differents setup.

There is the poduct : [Check this out](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

But git was not included and it's not easy to configure with wordpress... start your setup on the local one do you modifications and once it's ok push it on staging (sub-domain) and once it's done push it into production (mydomain.com)

Cheers